How to create a custom model binder attribute
I am not sure if this is even possible but I have a model as follows:
public class AddDocumentDTO
{
    [Required]
    [CustomAccessTokenAttribute]
    public required User Uploader {get; set;}
    
    [Required]
    public required int Id {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public required IFormFile File {get; set;}
}

I am trying to get the Uploader object to fill after model binds. I use this object quite often in many models and depends on access token and a simple query of my db with a claim that is in the access token:
    public async Task<UserDTO> GetByAccessToken()
    {
        var Id = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.User.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type.ToString() == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier").FirstOrDefault()!.Value.ToString();
        var userPOCO =  await _userRepository.GetAsync(Id);
        var userDTO = new UserDTO() {
            InternalUserNumber = userPOCO.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER,
            Username = userPOCO.USERNAME!,
            FirstName = userPOCO.FIRST_NAME!,
            LastName = userPOCO.LAST_NAME!,
            EmailAddress = userPOCO.EMAIL_ADDRESS!,
            WorkGroup = userPOCO.WORK_GROUP!,
            IsActive = userPOCO.ACTIVE_USER!,
            IsArmsUser = userPOCO.ARMS_USER,
            IsSysAdmin = userPOCO.SYSTEM_ADMIN,
            Avatar = userPOCO.AVATAR
        };
        return userDTO;
    }

If there is a way I can use a attribute tag or something that will indicate to the model binding to run this and fulfill this value from it will make life easier. Hoping there are not any security implications but I figure if the request has made it to trying to bind the model then its already made it past the Authorize filter so should be safe to fill this data. Regardless, is this even doable in a universal way I can apply to multiple models from the same tag? As of now a lot of my functions to my repository and service layers I have to either have a parameter for User Uploader to pass forward to get that data for my db or I have to manually bind it in to the model. I would love to automate this.

This sounds to me like a job for a middleware, not the model. The middleware should run after the user has logged in (middleware runs for all requests).

I do have a Authorization Middleware I run to ensure certain claims are there but is it not common to have a clean complete model with the current users details that are passed around ? I prefer not to have to inject some middlewear to get the user information in each repository. Seems like a lot of code compared to a nice little attribute added above the model that its suppose to bind with.
